# Daily cron at specific time

Tags: openshift

I would like to run a daily job at the OpenShift Express PaaS.
I know how to activate the cron cartridge on my app and how to add scripts into the correct cron folder.

But I have a special need to specify, at which time of the day the job will be executed.
E.g. "Every day at 10:30pm"

Is this possible with the OpenShift cron cartridge?
How do I configure a daily job with a specific time?

Regards,
Lars

Comment: I know nothing of open shift but the cron for 10:30pm everyday is `30 22 * * *`

Comment: @AbstractChaos From my knowledge, unfortunately the OpenShift cron cartridge is something different than the well known cron jobs. There is no such a crontab like config option.

Comment: Have you found any solutions? My problem is the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "minutely" cron job and only run your script if the current time is 10:30pm.

Like this :

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [ `date +%H:%M` == "22:30" ]
then
    bash scriptToRunAt10h30pm.sh
fi
```

Comment: I get an error if I try your example on OpenShift:
"/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Comment: Still an error after removing the first line:
"syntax error near unexpected token `fi'"

Comment: "unexpected end of file" without fi.

Comment: The ^M seems to say that you have Windows type line ending. Could you try again without the ^M at the end of each line? You could also use dos2unix or fromdos if you're using Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've converted the line endings, and it works perfectly now.